# How to cast DefaultListModel into List<Object>?

Tags: java

I have to put all elements from a `DefaultListModel` (in a listbox) into a `List<Object>`. How can I do that in Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to make a copy of the contents, then you can use `DefaultListModel.toArray` to get the data and construct your favourite `List` implementation with that. Alternatively you can loop over `ListModel.getElementAt` `ListModel.getSize` times.

If you want a live connection between the collections rather than a copy, use `AbstractList`:

```
 public static List<Object> asList(final DefaultListModel model) {
     return new AbstractList<Object>() {
          @Override public Object get(int index) {
              return        model.getElementAt(index);
          }
          ...
     };
 }
```

You may want to slide `Class.cast` in there, but there is an inherent problem with Swing types not being generic.

Answer (score 12):

```
Arrays.asList(model.toArray());
```

Comment: Depends if you want to copy the data or leave it connected.

Answer (score 1):

According to ye olde [API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html), you'll need to use the `elements()` method and iterate over them, adding them to a list.  `DefaultListModel` is not in the same hierarchy as the normal Collections classes.

OR use what jarnbjo suggested!